# Reading from a named pipe (and then stopping)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, mkfifo

I am trying to get two fortran programs to communicate through a named pipe but the reading program is hanging. My command look like this:

```
> mkfifo /tmp/myfifo
> ./app/fortw /tmp/myfifo &
> ./app/fortr /tmp/myfifo
```

where `fortw` prints the numbers 1 to 10 and 'fortr' reads them like this

```
open ( unit = nsave, file = outputfile , form = 'formatted', access = 'stream' )
do while ( .TRUE. )
read ( unit = nsave, fmt = *, end = 10), j
write( 6, *), j
end do

10 continue
```

It prints the numbers 1 - 6 and then hangs so i have to do `fg` then `C^C` to stop it.

If I replace `./app/fortr` with `cat`, or an equivalent c++ program, then I get the numbers 1 to 10 as expected so the problem seems to be with the reading not the writing. But if I read from a normal file rather than a fifo, `./app/fortr` gives the expected  result.

Should I expect to be able to get this to work, and it so, how?

UPDATE:

A more minimal example. If test contains the numbers 1 to 10, then

```
./app/fortr test
```

prints the numbers 1 to 10

but

```
 ./app/fortr <( cat test )
```

prints the numbers 1 to 6 and hangs

Comment: Sounds like you need a flush.  Try flush(6) after the write statement.  It is not standard fortran.  Alternatively, if after 10, you are ending the program, add close(6) before you terminate

Comment: `Flush` is standard Fortran. https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-188AE6E5-7E3A-41EA-AE71-F0726FC5024C.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, add flush(6) and close(6) to the reading program doesn't change the result. It still hangs after reading 6 numbers

Comment: Which compiler do you use? What code gives you iostat of read operations?

Comment: I am using gfortran. It seems to work for now if I add, `action = "read"` to the open command. I'm new to fortran though so I don't know why that helps or if it is likely to continue working.

Comment: @Peter I am now using `iostat = stat` in my read operations as well so I can check it.

Comment: @paco_uk , so what it gives you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read on closed named pipe blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670749/read-on-closed-named-pipe-blocks)