# Read on closed named pipe blocks

Tags: c, io, fortran, named-pipes

I am trying to read from a named pipe (FIFO) with Fortran.  Reading the data works, but the Fortran program does not seem to notice when the pipe is closed on the other end; reads simply block rather than getting an EOF.

Sample program:

```
program kitten
  character(256) :: buf

  open(22, file='test')
  do
     read(22, *) buf
     print*, trim(buf)
  end do
end program kitten
```

Now with

```
$ mkfifo test
$ echo -e '1\n2\n3' >test &
$ ./kitten
```

the program prints `1\n2\n3\n` as expected, but then simply hangs.

Instead, the program returns an error on EOF if

1. `test` is a regular file; or
2. you change `kitten` to read from STDIN and do `./kitten <test` or
3. `echo -e '1\n2\n3' | ./kitten`; or
4. you write an equivalent `kitten` program in C.

I tested this with `ifort 15.0.1` and `gfortran 4.9.2`, with the same results.

For C I used `gcc` and

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
        char buf[256];
        FILE *test;

        test = fopen("test", "r");

        while(fgets(buf, 256, test)) {
                printf(buf);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about fortran, but I do know you could reproduce the hanging behavior in C by using a read/write mode in your open (for example `fopen("test", "r+")`

The pipe doesn't get an EOF until the number of writable file descriptors on it drops to 0. When your read file descriptor is also writable, you never get EOF.

So my guess is that fortran opens in read/write mode by default, and you need to tell it not to do that. [This question about a fortran readonly flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26201876/2404501) may help.

Comment: That was right on target, adding `action='read'` solves the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: The default action (read/write/readwrite) for a connection is chosen by the compiler, rather than being specified by Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the C program.

A much better version would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void ) // properly declare main()
{
    char buf[256];
    FILE * test = NULL;

    if( NULL == (test = fopen("test", "r") ) ) // check for open error
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for test for read failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while(fgets(buf, 256, test) ) // exit loop when fgets encounters EOF
    {
        printf("%s\n",buf);
    }

    fclose( test ); // cleanup before exiting
    return 0; // properly supply a return value
}
```

Comment: Note: the function: `feof()` only returns true after trying to read past the end of the file.  In general, its' use is almost never justified

Comment: Yeah, my C is rusty to say the least `:-)`.  But the purpose here was not so much to create a “good” C program, just to test in a very simple way if it was Fortran that behaved this way or something strange on my system.  Anyway, thanks for the tip about `feof()`, which I implemented above.