# Fortran read from unit from Python

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes, filestream, fortran77

I'm looking to work with older Fortran subroutines that read from file-based unit numbers. Here is an example of some fixed-format FORTRAN77, `reader.f`:

```
      SUBROUTINE READER(IN,FVAL)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER IN
        REAL FVAL
        PRINT *,'READER READING FROM',IN
        READ(IN,*) FVAL
        PRINT *,'READER DONE',FVAL
        RETURN
      END
```

Compile this to a shared library, on Linux:

```
gfortran -fPIC -shared -o libdusty.so reader.f
```

And here is a basic [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) interface to the library object in Python:

```py
import os
from ctypes import CDLL, POINTER, c_int32, c_float, byref

c_int32_p = POINTER(c_int32)
c_float_p = POINTER(c_float)

so = CDLL('./libdusty.so')
reader = so.reader_

reader.argtypes = [c_int32_p, c_float_p]
reader.restype = None
```

Without an `open` statement, Fortran reads from the file `#.fort`, where `#` is the file unit number. So continuing from above, I get Python to write a temporary file to read from:

```py
fval_in = 43.21
fnum_in = 12
fname_in = 'fort.' + str(fnum_in)
print('Writing ' + fname_in)
with open(fname_in, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(str(fval_in) + '\n')

fval_out = c_float(0)
reader(byref(c_int32(fnum_in)), byref(fval_out))
print('Received fval: ' + str(fval_out.value))
os.unlink(fname_in)
```

From a console (which receives `stdout`), here the full output:

```py
Writing fort.12
 READER READING FROM          12
 READER DONE   43.2099991    
Received fval: 43.2099990845
```

**Question**: is a disk-based file object necessary, or is it possible to use a non-file-based stream to read from? A good candidate is [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), except that it does not provide `fileno()`. And a related question: is it possible to use a different file name other than `fort.12` in this example?

Comment: How much control do you have over changes to the Fortran components?

Comment: Assume no changes to Fortran source.

Comment: If you write to a unit number that is not connected to a file, then a file will be created.  The name of that file is processor dependent, and so for example, it does not need to be `fort.12`.  Now, it does turn out that many popular Fortran processor use a de facto standard naming convention that matches `fort.12`.  The Fortran standard does not require `fort.12` to be disk-based.  Of course, you can use a different filename, but that would require you to use the `OPEN` statement to connect the unit number 12 to the specific file.

Comment: @Steve yes the whole `fort.12` name is not really part of any standard, which is why I'd like to no do that. I can probably add another subroutine to the library to `OPEN` something that returns a valid unit number that the other subroutine can utilize. However, I'm still not sure if `OPEN` supports any kind of non-disk-based filestream (like a memory-map).

Comment: It really should be a file. But on Linux, many things are files, many devices are, for example.

Comment: A unit number is connected to an external file.  The Fortran standard says: _An external file is any file that exists in a medium external to the program._   Memory qualifies as "a medium external to", but you have to have a name associated with that memory-map thing so Fortran can connect a unit to it (perhaps, a named pipe).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be a memory mapped file as the example below shows. Beware, the C part is bodged from examples I found on StackOverflow and may contain serious errors (it certainly does contain too many typecasts) and also I am not completely sure when does the writing to disk happen. But you can certainly open other types of files, like `/dev/urandom` or even `/dev/mem` or [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670749/read-on-closed-named-pipe-blocks) as Steve mentioned in the comment (Python example below).

Note that the `fd`(c) or `fileno`(Python) is not the same as the Fortran file unit and cannot be used in Fortran in any way.

read_from_file.f90

```
      SUBROUTINE READER(IN,FVAL)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER IN
        REAL FVAL
        PRINT *,'READER READING FROM',IN
        READ(IN,*) FVAL
        PRINT *,'READER DONE',FVAL
        RETURN
      END

implicit none

integer :: iu

character(256) :: fname
real fval
call get_command_argument(1,value=fname)
open(newunit=iu, file=fname,access="stream", form="formatted")

call READER(iu, fval)
print *,fval

close(iu)
end
```

mmap.c

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

void* init(const char *file_path) {
    int fd = open(file_path, O_RDWR);

    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Could not open file for memory mapping");
        exit(1);
    }

    int result = lseek(fd, SIZE-1, SEEK_SET);
    if (result == -1) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = write(fd, "", 1);
    if (result != 1) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error writing last byte of the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    void *start_ptr = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    unsigned char *mem_buffer = (unsigned char *) start_ptr;

    if (mem_buffer == MAP_FAILED) {        
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Successfully mapped file.\n");
    return start_ptr;
}

void unmap(void *start_ptr) {


    if (munmap(start_ptr, SIZE) < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }


    printf("Successfully unmapped file.\n");
}

int main(){
  char *ptr;
  ptr = (char *)init("test");
  strcpy(ptr,"42\n\0");
  system("./read_from_file test");
  strcpy(ptr,"258\n\0");
  system("./read_from_file test");
  unmap(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

compile and run

```
gfortran read_from_file.f90 -o read_from_file
gfortran  mmap.c

 ./a.out 
Successfully mapped file.
 READER READING FROM         -10
 READER DONE   42.0000000    
   42.0000000    
 READER READING FROM         -10
 READER DONE   258.000000    
   258.000000    
Successfully unmapped file.
```

---

Python pipes example:

```
import os

path = "/tmp/pipe"
os.mkfifo(path)
print(path+"\n")
fifo = open(path, "w")
fifo.write("345\n")
fifo.close()
os.remove(path)
```

shell 1:

```
> python fifo.py
/tmp/pipe
```

shell 2:

```
>./read_from_file /tmp/pipe
 READER READING FROM         -10
 READER DONE   345.000000    
   345.000000
```

Comment: It must be changed to read an open file as Mike admitted as a possible change.

Comment: The subroutine can be kept as is. One can play with different opening modes and preparing the corresponding data on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that c/Python's fd/fileno are *not* interchangeable with Fortran's unit number. And yes, I don't mind adding fresh .f90/.c code with old code.

Comment: @MikeT See also the new example with Python.